# OptaPlanner VRPTW for a large setup customers with Pickup and Drop

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to create a route plan for a data set of customers having size around 20000. In a single route the vehicle might need to pick up or drop orders to customers. Hence the normal sizing hard constraint doesn't work for this problem.

I have created a shadow variable to store the vehicle load at each location in a trip. When the vehicle leaves the depot, the load is sum of all the elements needs to be dropped and each location I keep updating the load based of service type (pick up/drop).

The issue is after adding the shadow variable and the variable change listener the performance has degraded. The calculation per second has come down around 400. This is mainly because, to calculate the vehicle load at depot, I have loop through the chain. Is there an another efficient way to achieve the functionality?

Comment: How many chains do you have on average? What was your calculation per second before these changes?

Comment: I would implement it the same way, but it's a bit surprising to me that the perf impact is that because for Time Windowed VRP, I use the same mechanism.

Comment: The calculation per second before this change was around 3500. With the current data set I am testing with the average chain size is 400.

Comment: How many chains do you have on average? (So how many anchors do you have?)

Comment: 100 anchors are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement it the same way. And I am not aware of implementing it in a better way. The entire tail of the chain needs to be adjusted, and modified chain node needs to be checked for correct capacity.

If performance becomes a huge issue and your constraints won't change often (= little maintenance), look into writing a `JavaIncrementalScoreCalculator`: they are faster, but a lot more painful to maintain... In the VRP example, comment out the scoreDRL element and commment in the incrementalScoreCalculator element to get a taste on how much faster it is.

Comment: My constraints will change frequently and the business users are expected to change constraints. I was planning to use decision tables for the same.

Comment: Good idea to use decision tables, see dinner party seating example. Business flexibility is more important than getting the last bit of speed out of it.

Comment: The construction heuristic is taking a long time (around 2 hours) and initializes the solution in 20000. I am using FIRST_FIT_DECREASING and initializingScoreTrend as ONLY_DOWN as given in VRPTW example.